# ls formats date differently when run by cron

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, fedora, cron

In FC10, ls outputs dates in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM' format when called by command line or script. When called by cron, the dates are in format 'Mon DD HH:MM'.

What gives? why the change? I've checked env and alias, and nothing was obviously different between the shell and cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format depends on your locale settings ($LC_TIME, $LC_ALL, $LANG).

Comment: It was getting unset in /etc/profile.d/lang.sh which is run when the shell starts via: "export LC_TIME="

THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways I know to fix this, at least in Ubuntu Lucid.

Add this line at the top of you crontab file.

`LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"`

Or specify the time format for ls -l in your script.

```
ls -l --time-style=long-iso
```

I like this second way because it makes the script itself more portable. Also, every time you modify the environment for a crontab, you modify the environment for all scripts running in that crontab, and possibly introduce bugs in the other scripts that way.

Paul S

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is `--time-style` option. It might be specified, for example, somewhere in aliases for one of the users, the one who runs cron tasks or the one who runs the script from the command line.